# How to make it sure that an iframe content fits it?

Tags: php, html, iframe, browser

I have an iframe that calls an external page, like `<iframe src="http://pagewithimage.php/?parameter=xxx" style='border:0;width:100%'></iframe>`. The `pagewithimage.php` got an image that can be bigger that the iframe area, and undesired scroll bars appears. I'd like to scale the iframe content to fit it "100%", not more than it.

The code I'm using is this:

```html
> <div class='container-home-map'  style="background-color:#99CCCC;border-radius:10px;">
> <iframe src="http://pagewithimage.php/?parameters=AAA" style='border:0;width:100%;transform:scale(1.0)'></iframe>
> </div>
```

Where `http://pagewithimage.php` is a page that calls a code with `parameters` that generates an image with a size sent among the parameters. This image may be bigger that the iframe depending on the screen, so, My question is: can I scale the content to always fit the iframe? (not resize the iframe, but resize its content)

Comment: change the style of the iframe  tag or give it a class and style it with css

Comment: @lotfiolakehal ,  I have tried this `<iframe src="page" style='border:0;width:100%;transform:scale(1.0)'></iframe>` , but the `transform:scale()` changes the content relatively to the content itself, it doesn't make the content to fill "1" (or 100%) of the iframe. Is there any specific change you'd suggest?

Comment: edit your post and share the code let me try it here !!

Comment: Thank you, @lotfiolakehal . The code I'm using is pretty simple, I put it in the question as you said.

Comment: @lotfiolakehal you can check my website at [http://celestialchart.com](http://celestialchart.com). I'm talking about the sky map on the home page.